# downgrade java runtime from 1.8.0_60 to 1.8.0_51 on heroku

Tags: java, heroku

The recent version of Java runtime update `1.8.0_60` on heroku caused date format issue when signing a PUT request with AWS S3 library.

I am wondering how can we downgrade from `1.8.0_60` to `1.8.0_51` where the error did not happen for the time being.

I tried with system.properties file including

java.runtime.version=1.8.0_51

but it didn't work.

Could you help?

Thank you.

Cheers,
Zoltan

Comment: If downgrading does fix the issue, please let Heroku support know so we can file a bug against OpenJDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the JDK as a config variable like this:

```
heroku config:set JDK_URL_1_8=http://lang-jvm.s3.amazonaws.com/jdk/openjdk1.8.0_51-cedar14.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I also needed to redeploy to create a new slug.

Comment: Also found this. Appears to be a bug in aws-sdk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058431/aws-java-sdk-aws-authentication-requires-a-valid-date-or-x-amz-date-header