# How to exclude transitive dependencies with gradle and substitute it with another

Tags: java, gradle, configuration

I'm in situation similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058431/aws-java-sdk-aws-authentication-requires-a-valid-date-or-x-amz-date-header) 
(bug between JodaTime and versions of Java greater then 1.8u60).

So what I need is:

1. Upgrading to JodaTime version 2.8.1 or later.
2. The problem is: JodaTime is a transitive dependency in my project.

Build automation tool used in it is gradle. Need help to handle it.

**buildscript:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE")
        classpath("org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.2.1")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'

jar {
    baseName = 'xxxx'
    version = 'alpha'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.2.4.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:1.2.4.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.4.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:1.2.4.RELEASE")
    compile("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.2")
    compile("com.stripe:stripe-java:1.33.0")
    compile("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:3.2.1")
    compile("com.jolbox:bonecp:0.8.0.RELEASE")

    runtime("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.2.4.RELEASE")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { 
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:1.0.2.RELEASE" 
    }
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: It seems it can be done. Can you share the build.gradle script or at least relevant part of it?

Comment: @Opal ......................done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the following piece of code in `dependencies` block:

```
compile("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.2") {
     exclude group: 'joda-time', module: 'joda-time'
}
compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

put transitive false, and set between your dependencies the packages that you need rather that the ones in the transitive download.

Comment: This way you will exclude *all* the transitive dependencies of a given dependency - this is not always what you want/need.