# AmazonS3Exception with Elasticsearch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create snapshots directly on a S3 bucket, but it throw a AmazonS3Exception:

```
{"error":"SnapshotCreationException[[mysnapshotname:20161007-152322] failed to create snapshot]; nested: IOException[Unable to upload object preprodelasticsearch/snapshot-20161007-152322 due to AmazonS3Exception: AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 5B10DA56C7832AD2)]; ","status":500}
```

cleaned error:

```
AmazonS3Exception: AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header
```

I saw lot of [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058431/aws-java-sdk-aws-authentication-requires-a-valid-date-or-x-amz-date-header) indicate I need to upgrade my Java & AWS, here my versions :

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.10.24 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-48-generic botocore/1.4.15
```

Problem should be solved on 1.10.1 version of AWS, but still get it in 1.10.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws I used was 2.7.0, that is using Java SDK 1.9.34.

Just needed to migrate to elasticsearch-cloud-aws 2.7.1 which is using Java SDK 1.10.12, and it's sufficient to fix the problem